# Why does IE8 corrupt some zip files I download?

Tags: download, zip, internet-explorer-8

For some reason, when I download zip files with IE8, I get `Folder is invalid or corrupted`. But while downloading with Firefox or Chrome, I can open the file. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

Actually found out the issue, the files that threw the error were gzip files and found out needing a program like 7zip or winzip to open file.